# Range checking in Haskell's case?

Tags: haskell, case

Is there a valid way to do the following in Haskell:

```
case n of
    0     -> doThis
    1     -> doThat
    2     -> doAnother
    3..99 -> doDefault
```

other than to have 97 lines of "doDefault" ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
case n of
    0     -> doThis
    1     -> doThat
    2     -> doAnother
    _     -> doDefault
```

If you really need a range,

```
case n of
    0     -> doThis
    1     -> doThat
    2     -> doAnother
    x | 3 <= x && x < 100 -> doDefault
    _     -> reallyDoDefault
```

Comment: Makes me wish the Prelude defined "inRange lo hi v = lo <= v && v < hi"…

Answer (score 11):

Using guards! ;)

```
Foo n 
  | n == 0 = doThis
  | n == 1 = doThat
  | n == 2 = doAnother
  | (n >= 3 ) && (n <= 99) = doDefault
```

OR

```
  | n `elem` [3..99] =  doDefault
```

Comment: I personally like the `n \`elem\` [3..99]` version more than the one using inequalities.

Comment: Isn't the `elem`-based version significantly slower ? or is this optimized away ?

Comment: @b0fh : yep, elem is just `any (==)` which is O(n), afaik it is impossible to check membership with lower than O(n) complexity unless the collection you are checking is sorted somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can have the default case be the _ pattern, which matches on anything.

```
case n of
  0 -> doThis
  1 -> doThat
  2 -> doAnother
  _ -> doDefault
```

I'm not sure if that's quite what you're looking for, since it doesn't check the upper bound on the range there...  you might want to use guards instead.